# convert c++ to vb.net

Tags: c++, vb.net

i have this cpp code that i need an equvalent in vb.net or at leat know what its doing so i can figure out a conversion myself

```
const char * CResult::strnchr(const char *str, int len, char c) const
{
if (!str)
    return NULL;

const char *p = str;
while (len > 0)
{
    if (!*p)
        return NULL;
    if (*p == c)
        return p;
    p++;
    len--;
}
return NULL;
}
```

and this one

```
memcmp(prevprev, "ANY", 3)
```

thank you

Comment: your code is native(c++). VB.NET is not native language.in your code use pointer that is unsafe on .NET Applications.

Comment: `memcmp` == `prevprev.Equals("ANY")`

Comment: Or `.Compare` in the case of strings.

Comment: Why not Google `strnchr` and `memcmp`? That should tell you what they do.

Comment: thanks for your response. may i ask why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strnchr --  Find a character in a length limited string
```

See [this](http://gnugeneration.com/mirrors/kernel-api/r2320.html). You can do the same thing in VB.net using `String.IndexOf`, e.g.

```
Dim myString As String = "ABCDE"
Dim myInteger As Integer
myInteger = myString.IndexOf("D")  ' myInteger = 3
```

Example copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: More exact would be: `myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(c))`

Comment: hello, from your example `myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(c))` will return DE, since that is where the `D` was found. is this the behaviour as the c++ counterpart

Answer (score 1):

`strnchr` finds the location of the first occurrence of char `c` in string `str`. It returns a pointer to the character, which you cannot do in VB.Net, the closest you can do is get the offset of the character from the start of the string.

`memcmp(prevprev, "ANY", 3)` compares the three letters of "ANY" to the memory location at `prevprev`, effectively checking that prevprev contains a substring of ANY.

In VB.Net the first can be accomplished with the `IndexOf` member of the `String` type.
The second you need to use `SubString`  (again a member on the `String` type) to create a sub string of the string and check is it equal to "ANY".

```
Dim myString As String = "Any Hello World"
Dim AnyAtStart As Boolean = myString.SubString(0, 3) = "ANY")  ' Will be true '
Dim AnyAtSecond As Boolean = myString.SubString(1, 3) = "ANY")  ' Will be false '
```

Comment: `memcmp` is string comparison.  You're referring to `memcpy`.

Comment: `strnchr` returns a pointer to the first occurence, so effectively a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Finding VB.NET analogs or closely corresponding functions for many standard C functions is relatively simple using MSDN. Take memcmp() as example:
- MSDN source [memcmp, wmemcmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyaebf12.aspx) - "Compare characters in two buffers." 
- Find strings' comparison method in VB.NET - [String.Compare Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx#Y208)
But copying C source function by function into VB.NET can produce a strangely ineffective code for relatively small programs. And you will be puzzled every time looking for replacement of raw pointers used everywhere in C programs.

P.S. And what would you do if your *::strnchr* will be called differently from standard C function [strnchr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34ccac3%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)  - "Find a character in a string."?